# Express y in terms of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, regular-expressions

Question:

$$
\text{It is given that } y= \frac{3a+2}{2a-4} \text{and }x= \frac{a+3}{a+8} \\
$$

$$
\text{Express } y \text{ in terms of } x.
$$

From using $x$ to solve for $a$, I discovered that 
$$
a = \frac{8x-3}{1-x}
$$

Then I proceeded to substitute $a$ into $y$. I did this twice to ensure no mistakes are made, and my final answer for both was

$$
\frac{22x-7}{20x-10}
$$

There's a problem, the correct answer is 
$$
\frac{7-22x}{10-20x}
$$

This makes me want to cry, more so because I checked it twice and I was very careful about my working out, here it is:

$$
\frac{2+ 3(\frac{8x-3}{1-x})}{  2(\frac{8x-3}{1-x}) -4  }
$$

$$\rightarrow{}$$

$$
\frac{(\frac{2(1-x) + 3(8x-3)}{1-x})}{(\frac{-4(1-x)+2(8x-3)}{1-x})}
$$

$$\rightarrow{}$$

$$
\frac{2(1-x) + 3(8x-3)}{1-x} * \frac{1-x}{-4(1-x)+2(8x-3)}
$$

$$\rightarrow{}$$

$$
\frac{22x-7}{1-x} * \frac{1-x}{20x-10}
$$

The $(1-x)$'s cancel out
$$\rightarrow{}$$

$$
\frac{22x-7}{20x-10}
$$

Can someone please tell me as to what I did incorrectly in the process? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have actually done it perfectly. Multiply both numerator and denominator by $-1$ and you're done

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your answer is $$\frac{22x-7}{20x-10}$$

And the books "correct" answer is $$\frac{7-22x}{10-20x}$$

Yes? 
Notice what happens when you multiply both the numerator and denominator in your answer by $-1$? You're very welcome.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I was wondering whether or not I should do that but I wasn't sure, thank you again!

Comment: @SamirChahine you're welcome again. :D

Comment: @G.Bach you mean +1 for sass?

Comment: They are easy to get mixed up, aren't they.

Comment: yep. they are. ;)

Answer (score 11):

You got the correct answer. Just multiply both numerator and denominator by -1

$$\frac{22x-7}{20x-10} = \frac{-1}{-1} \times \frac{7-22x}{10-20x}$$

Comment: +1 This is a better answer than the one accepted since it makes explicit that OP original answer was correct.

Comment: @Taemyr maybe. My answer was completely tongue in cheek. I just wanted to amuse myself. Apparently it amused the OP as well.

Comment: Is there a reason, other than just to match the "correct" answer, to do the multiply by -1/-1?  Is there a rule or convention that says the "7 - 22x" form is preferred over the "22x - 7" form?

Comment: I don't think there is any rule but, I think there is a generally accepted (de facto?) convention of arranging terms in a polynomial order of decreasing powers.

Comment: @BradS. If you're working with polynomial rings then it's common to write the lowest degree terms first like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring)